# How to rewrite finding max contiguous subarray in Dynamic Programming using functional programming paradigm in ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, functional-programming, refactoring, dynamic-programming

I wrote the following code to find the contiguous subarray with maximum sum, which I tink pretty ugly:

The problem is my internal thinking of this problem (using DP) is imperative. How can I refactor this piece of code and make it more functional (and DRY)? Any recommendations on how to think algorithms in functional language? (maybe should be a sperate question though).

```
class Object
  def sum(lst)
    lst.reduce(:+)
  end
end

def dp_max_subarray(lst)
  i=0
  s=0
  while i<lst.length
    (i...lst.length).each do |j|
      t = sum lst[i..j]
      if t > s
        s= sum lst[i..j]
        next
      elsif t < 0
        i=j+1
        break
      end
    end
    i+=1
  end
  s
end
```

Comment: IIRC, this can be solved with 1 loop (greedy), no DP. Converting the greedy solution to higher order programming can be done with foldl (not sure the equivalent in ruby) and a 2-tuple (pair), which stores the max sum and the current sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm) for a O(n) Python solution. Translating it to functional Ruby is straightforward:

```
def max_subarray(xs)
  xs.inject([0, 0]) do |(max_so_far, max_up_to_here), x|
    new_max_up_to_here = [max_up_to_here + x, 0].max
    new_max_so_far = [max_so_far, new_max_up_to_here].max
    [new_max_so_far, new_max_up_to_here]
  end.first
end

xs = [31, -41, 59, 26, -53, 58, 97, -93, -23, 84]
max_subarray(xs) #=> 187
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this to a one-liner (not efficient and quite unreadable, though):

```
(0...arr.length).map{|start| (1..(arr.length-start)).map{|length| arr.slice(start, length).inject(:+)}.max}.max
```

Comment: Thanks! One liner is awesome! It is really hard to decide but for this case, I am trying to see some design patterns of rewriting DP code into functional flavor. Thanks the same~